# Save extra field on pivot table laravel/vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have an invoice table, an items table and a pivot table invoice_items. Inovice_items table has a field quantity that saves save quantity of each item on specific invoice.

Adding items in Invoice is created with Vue.js. How can I save quantity from vue in pivot table?

Code
ItemsModal

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="itemsModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Select an Item</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" data-backdrop="false" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#itemsModal"  aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" >
                        <select class="form-select  mb-3"  v-if="items" @change="getSelectedItem($event)">
                            <option selected>-Select an Item-</option>
                            <option v-for="item in items " 
                                    :key="item.id"
                                    :value="item.id"
                                    >{{ item.name }}</option>
                        </select>
                          <div class="m-4">
                              <label for="">Sales Price</label><br>
                              <p class="price">{{ selectedItem.sales_price }} $</p>
                         </div>
                          <div class="m-4">
                            <label for="">Quantity</label><br>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="selectedItem.quantity" name="quantity">
                         </div>
                          <div class="m-4">
                              <label for="">Total</label><br>
                                <p class="price">{{ totalPrice }} $</p>
                         </div>
                         <span class="btn btn-success" @click="addInvoiceItem">Add</span>
                    </div>
                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
    name: 'ItemsModal',
    mounted(){
        this.getItems()
    },
    data(){
        return{
            items: [],
            selectedItem: { 
            },

        }
    },
    methods:{
        getItems(){
            axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/all-items').then(response => {
                this.items = response.data
            })
        },
        getSelectedItem(event){
            axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/' + event.target.value).then(response => {
                this.selectedItem = response.data.item
            })
        },
        addInvoiceItem(){
            this.$emit('selected-item',  this.selectedItem )
            this.selectedItem = {}
            $('#itemsModal').toggle()
            $('.modal-backdrop').hide()
        }
    },
    computed:{
        totalPrice(){
            let total = 0;
            total += (this.selectedItem.sales_price * this.selectedItem.quantity)
            this.selectedItem.total = total
            return total
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

InvoiceController

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

             $invoice = Invoice::create([
            'invoice_no' => 'invoice',
            'invoice_date'=> $request->input('invoice_date'),
            'due_date'=> $request->input('due_date'),
            'customer_id'=> $request->input('customer_id'),
            'sub_total' => $request->input('sub_total'),
            'discount' => $request->input('discount'),
            'total' => $request->input('total')
        ]);

        return redirect('/invoices');
    }
```

Invoice.php

```
    protected $fillable = ['invoice_no', 'invoice_date', 'due_date','sub_total','discount','total','customer_id'];

    public function item(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class,'invoices_items')->withPivot('quantity');;
    }
```

Item.php

```
    protected $fillable= ['name','sales_price','purchase_price', 'category_id'];


    public function invoices(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Invoice::class, 'invoices_items')->withPivot('quantity');;
    }
```

I hope question is clear. Thankyou

Comment: use `attach()` method. `->attach($itemId, ['quantity' => $quantity]);` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: But how to get $quantity of that specific item? I tried with $request->input('quantity') but it returns null

Comment: format the data you're sending to the api, for example `items = [ ['itemId', 'quantity'], ['itemid', 'quantity'] ]` What have you tried, and what error are you encountering ?

Comment: I am getting quantity should not be null and when I try to give quantity a value still it doesn't store all  items ids on pivot table

Answer (score -1):

In the Invoices controller after saving the Invoice you should use the Many to Many relationship to `attach()` the item to the invoice here is how you do it .

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {     $invoice = Invoice::create([
            'invoice_no' => 'invoice',
            'invoice_date'=> $request->input('invoice_date'),
            'due_date'=> $request->input('due_date'),
            'customer_id'=> $request->input('customer_id'),
            'sub_total' => $request->input('sub_total'),
            'discount' => $request->input('discount'),
            'total' => $request->input('total')
        ]); 
$item = Item::findOrFail($request->get('item_id'));
    
    $item->invoices()->attach($invoice->primary_key, ['quantity' =>$request->get('quantity')]);

        return redirect('/invoices');
    }
```

Comment: It says: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'quantity' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `invoices_items` (`invoice_id`, `item_id`, `quantity`) values (13, 3, ?))

Comment: Are you having more than one items on the invoice ? if yes then you will need to iterate them inorder to get the accurate amount . that means  ```selectedItem: { }``` should be a list  ```selectedItems: []```

Comment: I changed that but still is not saving data on pivot table. Is not showing any error either

Comment: Shouldn't it be $invoice->item()->atach()..?

Comment: it works ,from any direction , either from invoice or Item side

Comment: It is not taking quantity from input. Quantity is null don't know why

Comment: Try ```$request->get('quantity');```